# WCF Service in Silverlight Application

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services

I have a Silverlight 5 application that is obtain data from a Silverlight-enabled WCF service in another project (my solution has a Silverlight project and a web project). There are a number of similar posts, but they're referring to web services hosted on a web server (proper web services).

I am aware that I have to tell the application where to find the service in both dev and prod. In dev, you'll have a port typically. My code to create a service client (with the correct EndpointAddress) is as such:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(
        Application.Current.Host.Source.Scheme.Equals("https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport : BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
Uri tempUri = new Uri("../PolicyDataService.svc", UriKind.Relative);
EndpointAddress servAddr = new EndpointAddress(tempUri);
PolicyDataServiceClient temp = new PolicyDataServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_PolicyDataService", servAddr);
return temp;
```

Now, where am I going wrong? In dev, everything works fine, but in prod the service is never being called. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on, but here are a few things that you can try if you haven't already:

1. Browse to the svc file on Prod and make sure you can access it (http://yoursite/PolicyDataService.svc)
2. Point your code to the prod location and make sure you can connect without any issue. Doing this will usually reveal what the problem is, provided you can connect.

Since you're using BasicHttpBinding, you shouldn't be running into security issues with the binding. I know this is pretty basic, but have to start somewhere.

Comment: So just to be clear, you're talking about having a svc on the filesystem as opposed to calling it "in-memory". Correct?